Can't install Cordova plugin from GitHub
I'm new to Cordova and I tried to add some packages to my project. I needed to install one specific package from GitHub, so I tried using following:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/acipher/pos
But it gave me following:
Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/acipher/pos via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clonepy4F6q\package.json'

I then tried adding few others from npm and from GitHub, both of them worked, meaning it has to be something wrong with the package itself. Since I'm new to Cordova, I canť really say, why it's not working.
Versions I'm using:
Cordova: 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Node.js: v17.9.1
Npm: 8.11.0


Just declare it in your config.xml such as
     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-someplugin" spec="git+https://github.com/something/cordova-plugin-someplugin" />

Just make sure to replace the plugin name and the plugin repo url

unfortunately didn't help at all, I added the line you suggested (<plugin name="cordova-plugin-pos-manager" spec="git+https://github.com/acipher/pos" />), but I still get the same errors. But thanks for the effort

If your case, the spec would be spec="git+https://github.com/acipher/pos.git"

Also that plugin has no package.json so I'm pretty sure it's too outaded.....
